# rsyslog sending custom log to remote sever

Tags: rsyslog

I have found an [answer](https://superuser.com/questions/494654/how-can-i-get-minecraft-s-log-into-rsyslog) on stackoverflow, but using same exact config, apart changing the mine to minecraft_server, returns:

```
Mar 25 05:21:29 gameserver rsyslogd[7027]: invalid or yet-unknown config file command 'InputFileStateFile
Mar 25 05:21:29 gameserver rsyslogd[7027]: invalid or yet-unknown config file command 'InputFileSeverity'
Mar 25 05:21:29 gameserver rsyslogd[7027]: invalid or yet-unknown config file command 'InputFileFacility'
Mar 25 05:21:29 gameserver rsyslogd[7027]: invalid or yet-unknown config file command 'InputRunFileMonito
Mar 25 05:21:29 gameserver rsyslogd[7027]: invalid or yet-unknown config file command 'InputFilePersistSt
Mar 25 05:21:29 gameserver rsyslogd[7027]: imfile: no files configured to be monitored - no input will be
Mar 25 05:21:29 gameserver rsyslogd[7027]: imuxsock: Acquired UNIX socket '/run/systemd/journal/syslog' (
Mar 25 05:21:29 gameserver rsyslogd[7027]: rsyslogd's groupid changed to 110
Mar 25 05:21:29 gameserver rsyslogd[7027]: rsyslogd's userid changed to 104
```

upon restarting rsyslog service.

I guess this is not the way to do custom logs in modern rsyslog? The answer was last edited in 2016.

I send files using /etc/rsyslog.conf additions:

```
*.* action(type="onfwd" taget="192.168.0.244" port="514" procotol="udp"
           action.resumeRetryCount="100" queue.type="linkedList" queue.size="10000")
```

So my question would be, how do I send the log file in a modern way?

I am running rsyslogd 8.1901 on Ubuntu 18.04

Answer (score 0):

Just checked this on same versions. I suspect your '$ModLoad' is after '$IncludeConfig /etc/rsyslog.d/*.conf'?

ModLoad should go before Include, otherwise included config will calli not-yet-initialized commands.